# Wifi.status() always returns WL_NO_SHIELD

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi

I've an Arduino Mega 2560 R3 and recently bought a Wifi Shield CC3000 from ebay http://www.ebay.de/itm/201405512301
They write that the firmware has the version ServicePack 1.11.1.
The WiFi shield is connected to the Arduino and green status light is on.

I try to run this example code:

```
void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
}

// check for the presence of the shield:
if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
  Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
  while(true);
}
...
```

It seems that Wifi.status() always returns WL_NO_SHIELD.
What can I do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using a CC3000 library, or the IDE's WiFi library that is written for the Wiznet chip?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved now.

- I imported the Adafruit_CC3000 library which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CC3000_Library
- I run the example but the output was chinese nonsense
- Instead of

  Serial.begin(115200);

  I used

  Serial.begin(9600);

  then the examples run without any problem

Thanks @Majenko. His question was very helpful.